# docker version command shows server version as "library-import"

Tags: docker, buildroot, docker-engine, docker-cli

I am trying to upgrade docker-engine to 23.0.0 as a part of buildroot installation. I have upgraded all the prerequisite packages i.e golang, containerd, docker-cli, runc, etc to the required higher version.
But when I execute the 'docker version' command it shows in the Server section **Version: library-import**. For other packages i.e golang, containerd, runc correct version is displayed
For the earlier version of docker-engine it shows the correct version i.e. 19.
Can anyone help me on why it is not showing the correct version for 23.0.0 and instead "library-import" is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

You can see similar "error" in the version in [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40675#issuecomment-598087351), or [this one](https://github.com/docker/buildx/discussions/1678).

This is generally linked to the Docker installation or upgrade process, due to an incomplete or incorrect installation. You are using a packager (buildroot), so this is not your issue.

Since you are upgrading Docker as part of a [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) setting, then I see a a patch (["fix btrfs handling"](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2024-March/687960.html)) which might have an impact depending on your configuration.
Plus, [docker-engine now requires `libseccomp` by default](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2023-February/661761.html): makes sure that is part of your dependencies.

As noted by [Arnout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957841/arnout) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78204731/docker-version-command-shows-server-version-as-library-import/78219201#comment137917728_78219201)

> To me this sounds like an issue in docker-engine itself, so perhaps open a ticket in the upstream tracker?
> You can also try to do a native build (using your OS's Go instead of the one from Buildroot). And you can try to do a build of an upstream checkout using Buildroot's Go.

Comment: I am updating the docker-engine as a part of buildroot installation. Not standalone.

Comment: @Jay Can you detail your current setup? What OS are you on?

Comment: x86_64 Ubuntu kernel:  5.10.194

Comment: @Jay OK.I have edited the answer.

Comment: @VonC The question comes from a packager, not a user, so the suggestion "uninstall/reinstall" makes no sense. When building docker-engine 23.0.0, it doesn't seem to report the correct version.

Comment: @Jay To me this sounds like an issue in docker-engine itself, so perhaps open a ticket in the upstream tracker? You can also try to do a native build (using your OS's Go instead of the one from Buildroot). And you can try to do a build of an upstream checkout using Buildroot's Go.

Comment: @Arnout I agree and have edited the answer to make that clearer. Note that the "buildroot" aspect was not present in the original question when I wrote this.